# Kubernetes on GCP - Getting Error message "failed to get previous image"

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I added the below property in the properties file of my microservice project to resolve an issue :

```
spring.cloud.config.enabled=false
```

Then I rebuilt the image with version 0.0.11-SNAPSHOT and deployed in kubernetes but it still refers an old copy of the image and shows below message in the "Events" section :

Container image "harish2610/mmv2-currency-exchange-service:0.0.11-SNAPSHOT" already present on machine

[image]

Now to resolve this, either I can delete this image or build a new image with new version 0.0.12-SNAPSHOT

I couldn't find a way to delete the old image from the machine hence I tried to build a new image with version 0.0.12-SNAPSHOT but then I receive the following error in the logs while builing the image :

```
INFO]     [creator]     ERROR: failed to get previous image: verifying image "docker.io/harish2610/mmv2-currency-exchange-service:0.0.12-SNAPSHOT": Error response from daemon: readlink /var/lib/docker/overlay2/                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      : invalid argument
```

How do I resolve this ? Please advise.

Comment: This is a long shot but maybe a change to `imagePullPolicy` to `Always` will help.

Comment: @DawidKruk I tried this option but unfortunately, it didn't help.